# Mocking NgRx store with selector in Angular 10

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, ngrx-store

I'm new to writing test cases, but I have been given a task to write tests for an app developed in Angular 10. We are using the ngrx to store the user information. Here is the function in ngOnInit:

```
this.store.pipe(select(userInfo)).subscribe((data) => {
    this.loggedInUser = data.userInfo;
    if(!this.loggedInUser) {
        this.loggedInUser = JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem('userInfo'));
    }
})
```

When I run my test case, I get an error saying "cannot find "userInfo" of undefined. I know it's an observable, but I don't know how I can supply the data object to the store. Any help would be appreciated. I can provide more information if needed

Comment: Check this out: https://ngrx.io/guide/store/testing. I usually do it the `Integration Testing` way but you have to provide the reducers in `StoreModule.forRoot` in the `imports` section of your `TestBed.configureTestingModule`.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a unit test, I would recommend testing only the `component` instance

The approach involves assuming that the store selector works (which makes sense since this selector is tested separately) and also that the `select` function works (we wouldn't want to test the framework functionality)

In your `Testbed` configurations `providers` array include a mock object for store

```json
    providers: [
      {
         provide: Store,
         useValue: {
            pipe:() => of({
              userInfo: {}
            }),
            dispatch: () => {}
         }

      }
    ]
```

The above Object will be provided in the test